# copy data with reducing the code lines

Tags: matlab

```
counter=1;
for i=1:50,
    if y(i)<U && y(i)>L
        Y(counter)=[y(i)];               % To copy the data from materix y to Y
        counter=counter+1;
    end
end
```

My question is:

Is there any way to reduce the lines of the code and use something instead of "counter" doing the same idea?

Note: `U` and `L` are numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use logical indexing instead.

```
U=50;
L =  1;
```

Create some random values. I multiply it with 100 to get a larger range.

```
A=rand(1,10).*100
A =

Columns 1 through 9:

92.3313   32.6929   33.4143   21.4837   71.6719   30.4625    7.5700   57.0943    6.4849

Column 10:

28.0583
```

Apply logical indexing

```
B=A(A<U & A>L)
B =

32.6929   33.4143   21.4837   30.4625    7.5700    6.4849   28.0583
```

Then you can use [find](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [ismember](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find the index if you want.

```
find(ismember(A,B)==1)

ans =

    2    3    4    6    7    9   10
```

Comment: Assume that K=find(ismember(A,B)==1);

and the results are 2   3   4   6   7   9   10
 

Then I want to take these index in matrix G, can I write 

G=G(find(ismember(A,B)==1))

I know this is not correct, but can you correct me please

Comment: Why is it not correct? Have you tried it? What do you get if you run `G(find(ismember(A,B)==1))`? Try and see....

Comment: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: That means that `length(G)` < 10. I can't really debug the code for you as I don't have all you code/data. In essence, you have to break the code down into the smallest bits, look at the output of each step and then make the statement more complex.

Comment: length of G is similar to the length of A

Comment: Similar or equal? There is a difference. You have to work this one out yourself, I'm afraid. I don't know what `G` is so it's impossible to say why your index exceeds matrix dimensions. Look at the sizes of `G` and `K`. Do you get an error if you do `G(10), G(9), G(8)` etc...